# Merge image with dynamically created QR code (HTML)

Tags: html, css, qr-code

[enter image description here][1]I use the qrcodejs-master library from davidshimjs to create a QR code on the site out of the current URL. Now, I want to use a .jpg and put it behind/next to the generated QR code via css, to use it as a background (for corporate identity primarily).

What I want to do is be able to print out these two images as if they were a single one. Which means I need to merge them, just as they are displayed via the css.

I tried to work with the canvas element, but that failed miserably. It appears to not accept the generated QR code as an image to draw on the canvas (probably because it needs to be a div, not an img.

Is there another way to do this, or something similar?

Here's the html code in question

```
<script> function drawIt(){
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var img1 = document.getElementById("Logo");
var img2 = document.getElementById("qrcode");
ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
ctx.drawImage(img2, 0, 0);
}
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="url" type="text"  style="display:none;" />
<a>
<img class = "Logo" id = "Logo" src="uttc.jpg"/>
<div class = "QR" id="qrcode"></div>    
</a>
<canvas id="canvas" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;" width="600" height="600">
</canvas>
<script> drawIt(); </script>
```

Edit: As requested, here is a picture of how its supposed to look. The small outline at the bottom is the canvas border, and as you can see, there is nothing in there. (Cant use embedded stuff yet, sry)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkiJn.png

Edit2: Here is a fiddle with all the code
https://jsfiddle.net/hq9740s2/2/

Comment: Can you show a pic of what it is supposed to do and what it is doing incorrectly?

Comment: If you want the elements next to one another, why not just float logo and qr code to the left, or make them inline-blocks?

Comment: Please provide a jsFiddle or codepen or snippet illustrating the problem (with all dependencies, but nothing more that what is needed). The library you're using can generate either a canvas or HTML or SVG. If a canvas, it's probably created as a child of you `div#qrcode`.

Comment: So, I just made a fiddle and put everything into it that I could. Sorry, Im not really familiar with all this yet. Which is probably also the reason it doesnt show any goddamn thing. But at least all my code is there. 
https://jsfiddle.net/hq9740s2/